Supabase corrupting file react native expo
when i try to upload a pdf file to the supabase bucket it uploads it but when i try to look at the pdf file manually through the supabase dashboard i cant open it and it gives me a error that reads "Error
Failed to load PDF document.
"
when i tried to get a list of the items and wont load but when i enter items manually it loads with no problem.
i dont know what to do, i think that when i upload them through the function it corrupted the file as i see that the file size got bigger (example: file size before the upload : 3kb, file size after the upload: 247 bytes) i dont know if that is the case but i dont know what else to do
this is my upload document function i am using react native expo
const uploadFile = async () => {
    try {
        let doc = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()
        const docName = doc.assets[0].name
        const docUri = doc.assets[0].uri
        const {data,error} = await supabase.storage
        .from('files')
        .upload(`${user.id}/${docName}`,decode(docUri),{
            contentType:'application/pdf'
        })
        if(data){
            getMedia(data)
        }else{
            console.log("no-go",error)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    // console.log(doc.assets[0].name)
}

